# Wordpress add a class to menu link

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I need your help. I need to add a specific class on the link that wordpress generates in the menu.
What should I edit?
The HTML output in my case is:

```
<nav class="nav" role="navigation">
<ul>
<li id="menu-item-8" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8"><a href="example.com">Sample Page</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-9"><a href="http://example.com">Prova sample</a></li>
</ul></nav
```

the code in the header file that generate the menu is:

```
    <!-- nav -->
    <nav class="nav" role="navigation">
    <?php html5blank_nav(); ?>
    </nav>
   <!-- /nav -->
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can do it through admin panel also

- In Appearance > Menus, click the Screen Options tab
- Under Show advanced menu properties, check CSS Classes
- Now expand any menu item to reveal the CSS Classes (optional) text
  input.
- Enter your class name and save your menu to apply the class to the
  menu item

http://sevenspark.com/how-to/how-to-add-a-custom-class-to-a-wordpress-menu-item

Comment: thanks!! It seems to work!! but it add the class on the <li> element and so I cannot style the <a> element as i want

Comment: No problem, please accept the answer if it has solved your issue. It will help others if they come to view the question

Comment: The problem is that it hasnt solve my problem. I need to add a class to the <a> element and with your tip it add the class to the <li> element.

Comment: you can style <a> in the li for the class defined in css. Is there any problem in doing this way? use li.myClass > a{ }

Answer (score 30):

Adds a class <a class=>
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_link_attributes

```
function add_specific_menu_location_atts( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    // check if the item is in the primary menu
    if( $args->menu == 'primary' ) {
      // add the desired attributes:
      $atts['class'] = 'menu-link-class';
    }
    return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_specific_menu_location_atts', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1):

After creating some WordPress sites based on the Bootstrap framework, i've come up with a solution of easily manipulating the WordPress navigation output by initializing the classes you want. This will make sure your enduser will not be needed to add all the custom classes when the client add's a new menu item.

Maybe it could help someone;

https://github.com/nickkuijpers/WordPress-Extended-Bootstrap-Nav-Walker

Answer (score -5):

Try edit html5blank_nav() function, in functions.php file

```
// HTML5 Blank navigation
function html5blank_nav()
{
wp_nav_menu(
array(
    'theme_location'  => 'header-menu',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => 'menu-{menu slug}-container',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
    )
);
}
```

Comment: @Giova.panasiti I never change that. But try add something to 'link_before'

Comment: it doesnt work. If I add something in link_before or just before it add what I type just as a simple plain text before the link.

Comment: @Giova.panasiti So maybe the above solution is simple and effective.

Comment: yes but with the above solution it adds a class to the <li> element so I cannot style the <a> element inside the navigation menu as I would like to

Comment: @Giova.panasiti You can't use li.class a{} ?